# WHERE statement based on CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a CASE statement based on the value of a variable:

```
WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
    AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
    AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam

    --new section below
    AND CASE (@orgTeamPK)
    WHEN '%' THEN
     (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL)
     ELSE
     (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
```

However my syntax appears to be off. How do I achieve what I am trying to do above?

Comment: You might want to include some test data, examples of what the params look like, and most importantly the desired outcome.  What you have so far is pretty cryptic.  Might be looking at a CTE or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Case needs to be terminated with an END.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need case stmt.

```
    WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND (
            (@orgTeamPK = '%' AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL) )
            OR
            (@orgTeamPK <> '%' AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Anup, you don't *need* a case statement, but imho using case makes the syntax more clear...
  Each piece in a where clause must be a "PREDICATE", i.e., it must evaluate to a Boolean.  The case statement in your where clause does not evaluate to a Boolean.  To fix, Change it as follows:

```
 WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
   AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
   AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam

   --new section below
   AND USR.OrganizationalTeamId Like 
        CASE (@orgTeamPK) WHEN '%' THEN coalesce(@orgTeamPK, USR.OrganizationalTeamId)
              ELSE @orgTeamPK end
```